# Is the closure of a subgroup of a quasitopological group a subgroup?

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

The closure of a subgroup in a topological group is a subgroup. Is the same true for a [quasitopological group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group#Generalizations)?

Comment: Here's a proposed counterexample that I'd love for someone to check if possible: in Example 2 of [this article of Ravsky](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.11215.pdf), it might be the case that the closure of the subgroup $\{1,e^{2\pi i/3},e^{4\pi i/3}\}$ is the non-subgroup $\{1,e^{\pi i/3},e^{2\pi i/3},e^{4\pi i/3},e^{5\pi i/3}\}$.

Comment: @GregMartin what is meant by $\mathbb C\setminus \{(-1,0)\}$? is it $\mathbb C\setminus (-1,0)$? Perhaps $\mathbb T\setminus \{-1,1\}$

Comment: or $\Bbb T\setminus\{-1\}$, since $-1=-1+0i$ might be what they meant by $(-1,0)$. I'm not convinced my idea works btw

Comment: crossposted at MO https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380748/. Actually *"I've found out"* should be *"I was told in a comment at MO"*

Comment: @GregMartin, [re](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977297/is-the-closure-of-a-subgroup-of-a-quasitopological-group-a-subgroup#comment8205834_3977297), with the corrections to the notation above, I think that the neighbourhood $e^{\pi i/3}U_2 = \{e^{i t} : t \in (\pi/3 - 1, \pi/3 + 1) \cup (4\pi/3 - 1, 4\pi/3 + 1)\} \setminus \{e^{4\pi i/3}\}$ of $e^{\pi i/3}$ does not intersect $H = \{1, e^{2\pi i/3}, e^{4\pi i/3}\}$, since $0 < \pi/3 - 1 < \pi/3 + 1 < 2\pi/3 < 4\pi/3 - 1 < 4\pi/3 + 1 < 2\pi$, and similarly for $e^{5\pi i/3}$, so neither is in the closure of $H$.

Comment: ($U_2$ [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3977297/is-the-closure-of-a-subgroup-of-a-quasitopological-group-a-subgroup#comment8209728_3977297) should be $U_1$, although of course $U_2 \subseteq U_1$ works as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have it as an answer, my [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380748/is-the-closure-of-a-discrete-subgroup-of-a-quasitopological-group-a-subgroup#comment967295_380748) from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380748/is-the-closure-of-a-discrete-subgroup-of-a-quasitopological-group-a-subgroup):

Yes: if $h_n \to g$ and $h'_m \to g'$, then $h_n h'_m \to g h'_m$ for each $m$, so each $g h'_m$ lies in the closure; and then $g h'_m \to g g'$, so $g g'$ lies in the closure.  (Identity and inverses are obvious.)

Comment: I deleted that question which was different from this question with an additional discreteness condition. But the condition played no role.